# How to fetch records categorywise from same table by cross join

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MYSQL 
I need the records with cross join

The Table are below

```
table1
id name userid
1  A     1
2  B     1
3  C     1
4  D     1
5  E     1

table2
id name  catid
1  F      1
2  G      1
3  H      2
4  I      2
```

I want the output like below by Mysql Query 
the column vale of fist table A should be concatenate with each category name of second table and different category value also concatenate together
Like **A** **G**(table2.catid-1) **H**(table2.cateid-2) and so on

the Final output should be below

```
Final
A F H
A G H
A F I
A G I
B F H
B G H
B F I
B G I
C F H
C G H
C F I
C G I
D F H
D G H
D F I
D G I
E F H
E G H
E F I
E G I
```

how should i write the Mysql Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you want such output - or what the IDs and category IDs really mean, but you can get your output with this:

```
select t1.name, t21.name, t22.name
from table1 t1
join table2 t21 on t21.catid=1
join table2 t22 on t22.catid=2
order by t1.name, t22.name, t21.name
```

Comment: it should be order by t1.name, t22.name,t21.name ,u wrote that in hurry i guess :)

Comment: @HardikBhalani D'oh! Of course, thanks.  I tested it in my sandbox db and changed it there, but didn't when copy/paste - I updated the answer.